# WPF Binding Overhead

Tags: wpf, binding

I am learning about WPF. I have now come to binding. Does the binding rely on reflection when using `INotifyPropertyChanged` and is so, what is the price? I am considering using WPF for displaying data being streaming via UDP, but I fear that the overhead might be too great compared to WinForms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613546.aspx) about it. This is a pretty common question I hear all the time.

But my thought is, unless you're running into a serious edge case scenario, you want to use binding in WPF. That's the way the whole system is designed.

Answer (score 6):

Performance of binding depends on the type of object being bound. Reflection isn't used with respect to INotifyPropertyChanged, but is when resolving CLR properties.

Microsoft has a great write up on this: ["Optimizing Performance: Data Binding"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613546.aspx).

Key details related to performance:

> If the source object is a CLR object and the source property is a CLR
>   property, the Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) data binding
>   engine has to first use reflection on the source object ... *This
>   sequence of reflection operations is potentially very time-consuming*
>   from a performance perspective.
>
> The second method for resolving object references involves a CLR
>   source object that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface,
>   and a source property that is a CLR property. In this case, the data
>   binding engine *uses reflection* directly on the source type and gets
>   the required property. This is still not the optimal method, but it
>   *will cost less in working set requirements than the first method*.
>
> The third method for resolving object references involves a source
>   object that is a DependencyObject and a source property that is a
>   DependencyProperty. In this case, the data binding engine *does not
>   need to use reflection*. Instead, the property engine and the data
>   binding engine together resolve the property reference independently.
>   *This is the optimal method* for resolving object references used for data 
>   binding.
>
> ...
>
> WPF allows you to data bind to XML content; however, *data binding to
>   XML content is slower* than data binding to CLR objects. Do not convert
>   CLR object data to XML if the only purpose is for data binding.

<sub>(*emphasis* added)</sub>

Comment: It's worth noting that this Reflection overhead is only incurred when you first parse the initial PropertyPath for the Binding.  There is a rather complex PropertyPathWorker behind the scenes that caches the binding expression in a parsed form, which allows it to react to notified changes anywhere in the path, without having to re-Reflect to get the necessary metadata.